# How to read some elements of a matrix from disk C++

Tags: c++, matrix, io

I have a code where I'm reading `1024x1024 float matrix` from disk then I'm getting some elements of it and doing some process on the new matrix as follows.

```
// mask is the 1Kx1K matrix that 1/64 element of it are 1 other elements are 0;
// it is a mask for **Mat data** 

string filename = "filepath";
Mat data(1024,1024,CV_32F);
readMatrix(filename, data);

Mat smallMat(128,128,CV_32F);
getSmallerMat(data, mask, smallMat);
```

I read from float Mat from disk and fill smallMat using `getSmallerMat(...)` which is simply two for loops checking `if mask(i,j) == 1, write to next position in smallMat`

```
readMatrix(string fpath,Mat& data){
    FILE* fp = fopen(fpath.c_str(),"rb");
    if (!fp)perror("fopen");
    int size = 1024;
    data.create(size,size,CV_32F);

    float* buffer= new float[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;++i)   {
        fread(buffer,sizeof(float),size,fp);
        for(int j=0;j<size;++j){
            data.at<float>(i,j)=buffer[j];
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(buffer);
}
```

What I want to do is just reading matrix elements whose corresponding value in mask is equal to 1. My problem is how will I pick `(i,j)-th element` from the disk.

Reading whole matrix and squeezing it takes 15 ms, I want to make it faster but I couldn't achieve to do it.

[image: mask]

Consider this pic is my `mask` matrix. I want to read only white pixels only.

Thanks,

Comment: You are using `new []` but then `free`? Really not a good idea. You should pick C or pick C++ and stick with it.

Comment: I didn't notice it. I changed `free` to `delete` but what is the problem with it? Is it just related to using two languages or is there any other problem?

Comment: If you `new`, you should `delete`. Also if you are going to write C++, you should always `new` and `delete` as a habit. `malloc` and `free` do not call constructors and destructors, and while that is not a problem with a `float`, it could get you into trouble later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I have understood your problem or not; but if you want to read i,j th element from a file which contains the only float elements you should be able to get it like below -

```
float get(int i, int j, int rowsize, FILE * fp) {
    float retVal = -1.0f; //-infinity may be?
    // if you need restoring the stream pos
    long lastPos = ftell(fp);
    // ff to i*row + j
    fseek(fp , ((i * rowsize) + j) * sizeof(float), SEEK_SET);
    fread((unsigned char *)&retVal, sizeof(float), 1, fp);
    // restore prevpos
    // bla bla bla
    return retVal;
}
```

You should be able to read any file which contains fixed size element very fast using the fseek and some arithmatic from start end or current file pointer. check the [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/?kw=fread) documentation for more details.

Comment: should be constant regardless of N

Comment: Thanks for help, but I tried, `for(i=0; i<3;i++) fseek(fp,i,SEEK_SET); fread((uchar *)&retval, ....); cout << retVal << " ";`. Isn't it supposed to print (0,0),(1,0) and (2,0)-th elements of fp? (0,0) is printed correctly, others not. Is there anyy mistake related to that print out code?

Comment: `fseek(fp , ((i * rowsize) + j)*sizeof(float), SEEK_SET);` When I change this line, it works correct

Comment: @smttsp: yes my mistake, I remembered to add the size but forgot in the actual code to include. Because when you see the fseek() prototype, offset seeks the cursor by offset bytes so you need to move the position by multiplicative of sizeof(float) bytes (obviously). edited the answer.

Comment: This is not working with O(1). How could I keep lastPos, then go to next position? I mean, I go to 100th element, in the next turn, I will go to 105th element by just incrementing 5 to previous position rather than starting from 0th location?

Comment: @smttsp long targetpos = (((i * rowsize) + j) * sizeof(float)) - ftell(fp);

fseek(fp, targetpos, SEEK_CUR);

I think the delay is due to file access. not for computation.

Comment: When I read whole matrix, it takes 10 ms. If I read 1.5% of it with this method, it takes 53 ms.

Comment: If you read the whole matrix as one it will take less time (1 fn call + 1 disk access + copy) where if you perform several operation it will take much time (multiple fn call + multiple disk access + assign).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that i understand the question correctly, but are you looking for a method to access data on the hard disk more quickly than via a stream? For finding some specific matrix element (i,j) in your stream you need to read the whole file (in the worst case), i.e. the complexity is linear, this can't be helped.
However, if you actually know the position in the fiel exactly (i.e. if you use a fixed length format for representing your doubles, etc.) seekg
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/
should be faster than actually reading all characters until the desired position.

EDIT:
Given the discussion in comments to other answers I want to stress that using some seek in a file stream is O(N), hence multiple seeks for specific element will be way slower than just reading the whole file. I am not aware of a method to access data stored on hard disk in O(1). However, if all you ever need is matrices which are zero outside your mask, you should familiarize yourself with the concept of **sparse matrices**. 
See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix and the documentation for your library, e.g. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_sparse.htm

Answer (score 0):

From your code it appears your matrix is stored in binary as a memory image of the floats. What you want is go directly to the index on the disk where the (i,j) float is. You can compute this position using the following formula: `index = i*colWidth+j` where `colWidth` is 1024 in your case. You can use `fseek` and `ftell` to move your position and get your position in the file opened by `fopen`.